# Como instalar Npgsql como um provedor de dados para ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, visual-studio-2015

Eu li tudo o que possa se imaginar, mas estou sem sorte. No Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise update 1, segui exatamente os passos como descreve o tutorial na página http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html:

- Baixei e instalei: Setup_NpgsqlDdexProvider;
- Adicionei ao meu projeto os pacote
- Instalei o pacote recomendado do `npgsql 3.1.6`, ele também instalou `Npgsql` no `GAC ea machine.config`, o `EntityFramework6.Npgsql`;
- Instalei os pacotes no projeto pelo `nuget`:

mudou o `machine.config` em `% SystemRoot% \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ CONFIG e% SystemRoot% \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ CONFIG para Npgsql versão 3.1.6`

Mas quando eu vou para adicionar a dados de entidade `ADO.NET`, eu verifico modelo do banco de dados. Defino a conexão, testo e ele me retorna sucesso no entanto ao retornar da janela de conexão, o Assistente fecha imediatamente.